# What's the purpose of gruntjs server task?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm learning how to propel use gruntjs. I found the [server task](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt/blob/master/docs/task_server.md) but I can't get the point.

Can i use the server task mapping concatenated/minified files to test my application (uses backbone.js) without moving or placing source files in web server root? Without apache for example.

If no, what's the supposed use of server task?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The `server` task is used to start a static server with the `base` path set as the web root.

Example: Serve `./web-root` as `http://localhost:8080/`:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  server: {
    port: 8080,
    base: './web-root'
  }
});
```

It will function similar to an Apache server, serving up static files based on their path, but uses the [http module](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html) via [connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) to set it up ([source](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt)).

If you need it to serve more than just static files, then you'll want to consider [defining a custom `server` task](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt/blob/master/docs/task_server.md#roll-your-own-%E2%9A%91):

```
grunt.registerTask('server', 'Start a custom web server.', function() {
  grunt.log.writeln('Starting web server on port 1234.');
  require('./server.js').listen(1234);
});
```

And custom server instance:

```
// server.js
var http = require('http');
module.exports = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    // ...
});
```

---

> Can I use the server task mapping concatenated/minified files to test my application [...]

Concatenation and minification have their own dedicated tasks -- [`concat`](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt/blob/master/docs/task_concat.md) and [`min`](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt/blob/master/docs/task_min.md) -- but could be used along with a `server` task to accomplish all 3.

---

#### Edit

If you want it to persist the server for a while (as well as grunt), you could [define the task as asynchronous](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt/blob/master/docs/types_of_tasks.md#custom-tasks-%E2%9A%91) (with the server's [`'close'` event](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_close)):

```
grunt.registerTask('server', 'Start a custom web server.', function() {
  var done = this.async();
  grunt.log.writeln('Starting web server on port 1234.');
  require('./server.js').listen(1234).on('close', done);
});
```

Comment: Well thanks. I already have concat/min/lint tasks, but when i try to run the server (`grunt server` command) configured as `http://localhost:8080` with files and folders, it soon quits with "task done" message.

Comment: @Gremo That's actually [by design](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt/blob/master/docs/task_server.md#about-%E2%9A%91): "*Once grunt's tasks have completed, the web server stops.*" It's not intended for starting the server for indefinite/production use; just for having it available to other tasks, especially tests that could imitate a web-client ([`http.request()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) or [`request`](https://npmjs.org/package/request)).

Comment: That is i can't use the server just for running my application, right?

Comment: @Gremo Not normally. You could define the custom task as asynchronous, which will keep grunt alive while the server is still running. See my edit.

Comment: The server runs for as long as grunt is busy with tasks. A quick and dirty way to keep it opened is with grunt.registerTask("run", "server watch");. To cancel the watch will close the browser.

Comment: props, @widged! `grunt.registerTask("run", "server watch")` is very clever. Why not make this a separate answer so it's more visible?

Comment: And now, how do I use node-inspector? I have the "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED Is node running with --debug port 5858?" error

Comment: Live reload doesn't work anymore, and are loaded some cached files.. Don't know why, but is not the last version I have in my app folder.

Comment: @Totty Sorry. But, comments aren't the best place further Q&A. Have you posted those as questions?

Comment: Not yet, but I will soon.

Answer (score 55):

> The `server` task is now the `connect` task and it's included in the [`grunt-contrib-connect`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect) package.

The `connect` task starts a connect web server.

Install this plugin with this command:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-connect --save-dev
```

> Note: `--save-dev` includes the package in your `devDependencies`, see https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html

Once the plugin has been installed, it may be enabled inside your Gruntfile with this line of JavaScript:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
```

*Run this task with the `grunt connect` command.*

Note that this server only runs as long as grunt is running. Once grunt's tasks have completed, the web server stops. This behavior can be changed with the [`keepalive`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect#keepalive) option, and can be enabled ad-hoc by running the task like `grunt connect:targetname:keepalive`. `targetname` is equal to "server" in the code sample below.

In this example, `grunt connect` (or more verbosely, `grunt connect:server`) will start a static web server at `http://localhost:9001/`, with its base path set to the `www-root` directory relative to the Gruntfile, and any tasks run afterwards will be able to access it.

```
// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
  connect: {
    server: {
      options: {
        port: 9001,
        base: 'www-root'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

The point of the server task is to have quick and dirty access to static files for testing. grunt server IS NOT a production server environment. It really should only be used during the grunt lifecycle to get static testing assets to the testing environment. Use a full-fledged server, possibly controlled by the NPM lifecycle scripts, for production environments.