# Use Grunt to start Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gruntjs

I would like to add a task to my Gruntfile in order to start my Express server instead of the default server. 
I tried to had a task and require("server.js") but I think this isn't the right way to do that: running "grunt mytask" there are no errors but the command return immediately..and the express server isn't listening
Thank you for your help !

Comment: The answer to this is already posted here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943212/whats-the-purpose-of-gruntjs-server-task

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I couldn't find by myself this answer.. but just before seeing your suggestion I came out with the same solution, but it didn't seem to me the best way to handle this problem! but now seems to be the right way !

Comment: @EmlynMurphy Could you post a complete answer so that it can be marked as accepted?

Answer (score 3):

you could use [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) to execute commands in the terminal:

for instance if you have a app.js file that configures your express app you can start it from the command line with 'node app.js'

to configure with grunt shell you'd use something like:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  shell: {
    launchExpress: {
      options: {
        stdout: true
      },
      command: 'node app.js'
    }
  }
});
```